# Disable wildfly boot logs

Tags: json, logging, jboss, wildfly

```
=========================================================================


JBoss Bootstrap Environment


JBOSS_HOME: /opt/jboss/wildfly


JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java


JAVA_OPTS: -server -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -server -Djava.awt.headless=false -DnmsServer=true -Djava.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactory


=========================================================================
```

At the start of the wildfly server, we can see those kinds of logs printed by I believe standalone.sh script

I have a requirement that all stdout logs should be in JSON format. All other logs except those printed by sh scripts are configured in standalone.xml and work fine as JSON. Is that possible somehow to configure those boot logs (Without touching sh scripts) or maybe remove them entirely?

Comment: Just as a note I think it's a reasonable enhancement request to disable that output with something like an environment variable for cases like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `standalone.sh` (starting at line 321 in at least Wildfly 24.0.1) there is:

```
# Display our environment
echo "========================================================================="
echo ""
echo "  JBoss Bootstrap Environment"
echo ""
echo "  JBOSS_HOME: $JBOSS_HOME"
echo ""
echo "  JAVA: $JAVA"
echo ""
echo "  JAVA_OPTS: $JAVA_OPTS"
echo ""
echo "========================================================================="
echo ""
```

If you can't modify the default `standalone.sh` then you'll need to make a copy of it and remove this.  Note that there are other `echo` statements in the file in the case of an error.

Comment: Thanks. this is actually what I did. unfortunately seems to be the only option